# EF7 all related entities in ICollection loaded twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I have two entities, Function and Department with a Many to Many table in between.

```cs
public class Department 
{
    public Department()
    {
        DepartmentFunctions = new HashSet<DepartmentFunction>();
        PersonFunctions = new HashSet<PersonFunction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentFunction> DepartmentFunctions { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Function
{
    public Function()
    {
        DepartmentFunctions = new HashSet<DepartmentFunction>();
        FunctionTaskProfiles = new HashSet<FunctionTaskProfile>();
        PersonFunctions = new HashSet<PersonFunction>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? ItemOrder { get; set; }
    

    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentFunction> DepartmentFunctions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FunctionTaskProfile> FunctionTaskProfiles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonFunction> PersonFunctions { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class DepartmentFunction 
{
    
    public int FunctionId { set; get; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Function Function { get; set; }
}
```

When the departmentfunction on either entity is loaded, either with eager loading or lazy loading, every unique DepartmentFunction is listed twice. This problem occured after updating from EF core 5 to EF core 7. I have not changed anything with that update.

I have tried explicitly configuring the relation like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentFunction>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new {FunctieId = e.FunctionId, AfdelingId = e.DepartmentId})
            .HasName("PK__Afdeling__591131EC594F97A1");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Department)
            .WithMany(p => p.DepartmentFunctions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Function)
            .WithMany(p => p.DepartmentFunctions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.FunctionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

I have also seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255728/ef-core-eager-loading-loads-same-data-multiple-times), however, implementing this one would involve changing hundreds of references.

Comment: As a workaround, I added a backing field to the affected collections and a DistinctBy() in the property getter.

Comment: Could you also add `PersonFunction` and the related propeties + mapping? It seems that they interfere somehow. Also, test if the many-to-many relationship acts normal if you temporarily remove these `PersonFunction` relationships.